# Google AdsApp campaign selector filter by label name in the new experience

Tags: google-ads-script

Next month the new experience for Google Ads Script will be enabled and I have to adapt my script to work with it.

In my script I look for campaigns with an specific label name:

```
  var selector = AdsApp
    .campaigns()
    .withCondition("LabelNames CONTAINS_ALL ['my-label']")
```

With the new experience it seems that the unique way to get all the campaigns filtered by a label has to be done using the [label's resource name](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_campaignselector#withCondition_1).

```
withCondition("campaign.labels CONTAINS ANY ('customers/1234567890/labels/123','customers/1234567890/labels/456')"). The value is a list of label resource names.
```

As I don't know that value, the unique way I found is to iterate the enabled campaigns, get the labels and check if the label I want exists. If exists I continue executing the code.

Is there a way I can get the campaigns filtered by the label name instead of the resource name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is not possible so the unique way I found is getting the Label resource name first and then retrieve the campaigns.

```
let label;
const labelIterator = AdsApp.labels().withCondition('label.name = "my_label"').get();
while (labelIterator.hasNext()) {
  label = labelIterator.next();
}

const campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns()
  .withCondition('campaign.status = ENABLED')
  .withCondition(`campaign.labels CONTAINS ALL ('${label.getResourceName()}')`)
  .get();
```

This way I only perform two request and I get the campaigns that I need.